# Add to end of URL automatically

Tags: php, html

I am creating a tool for people to download, and install on their own. An easy install is what we are guided toward, and we will need a string like this: `?example=%s&example2=%m`; to automatically be added to the end of a URL like this: http://example.com; automatically when the page is visited, without page redirection or anything.

So if a user downloads this, and installs it, you shall not have to make the URL: `http://example.com?example=%s&example2=%m` on their own.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Do you want to post a variable? Do you want the download to start automatically? Why does the url have to look like that?

Comment: Where at all did I say I want the download to start automatically? I clearly stated what I need, don't ask why, its a clear objective, I need a string to be added to the end of a url automatically when you go to the basic url.

Comment: If adding text to the url is your only objective then using the javascript feroz provided will do the trick... enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are asking  [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ex1='feroz';
var ex2='akbar';
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?example='+ex1+'&example2='+ex2;
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using it in the head and body, this is what I am using:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var 1='%s';
var 2='%m';
if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?steamid='+1+'&mapname='+2;
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
</script>